# Why does Merge then Dissolve return ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset ... does not exist or is not supported?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, merge, dissolve, error-000732

I'm not sure why I'm running into this problem. I thought it might have something to do with the merged file being locked or open, but I don't see a "LOCK" file being created in Windows Explorer.

I'm simply trying to [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) a bunch of files and then [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) the merged file. Here's my script:

```
workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "Folder")
for workspace in workspaces:

    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    shps = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL")

    ## Process: Merge Layers
    descWorkspace = arcpy.Describe(workspace)
    workspaceName = descWorkspace.baseName

    mergeOutput = workspaceName+"_merge"
    arcpy.Merge_management(shps, mergeOutput)

    ## Process: Dissolving Features              <--HERE IS WHERE I'M HAVING PROBLEMS
    disInput = mergeOutput
    disOutput = mergeOutput+"_dis"
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(disInput, disOutput)
```

This is the error that I'm getting after the merge runs successfully: `ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset Bus04_merge does not exist or is not supported`

I'm obviously missing a step here... (or using incorrect parameters, but I can't figure out in what way)

Comment: What happens when you print shps?  Is the list of shapefiles in "workspace" displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the following line in your code:

```
mergeOutput = workspaceName+"_merge"
```

into:

```
mergeOutput = workspaceName+"_merge.shp"
```

Thanks,

meryloo

Comment: I ended up rewriting much of the code, so I can't try that out exactly, BUT, I think ultimately I did realize that changing that to .shp DID help, so great suggestion. Thank you!!